# I installed all jars and related settings correctly but still Emulator not working in Android Studio 2.3.2 Version

Tags: android-studio

WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OS compatibility issue you have to reinstall Studio.